# How to use Url::remember in yii2

Tags: yii2

I want to create a link on my error page to take user back to the previous link.
Suppose the current URL is http://example.com/site/product, and a user try to view 
http://example.com/site/product?id=100 and a product with id =100 does not exit, the system should throw 404 error to the error page, now if i want to create a link to take the user back to http://example.com/site/product the previous URl how do I make this work. i can make this work by  hardcoding this in my error views file, but i want it dynamically as i have many controller an action using the same view file.

I try this in my site conteoller

```
controller/site

public function actions()
{
     $url = Url::remember();
    return [
        'error' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
        ],

       $this->render('error',['url'=>$url]), 
    ];
}
```

and try to get the value the in error view file like this

```
   /views/site/error.php

  <p>
    <?= Html::a('go back', [$url)?>

</p>
```

but it has no vaule..
please any good idea on how to make this work, am also open to new solution

Comment: use this way: `$url = Url::previous();
<?= Html::a('go back', [$url])?>
`

Answer (score 2):

this is form Yii2 Guide  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-helper-url.html#remember-urls

> There are cases when you need to remember URL and afterwards use it
>   during processing of the one of sequential requests. It can be
>   achieved in the following way:
>
> ```
> // Remember current URL  Url::remember();
>
> // Remember URL specified. See Url::to() for argument format.
> Url::remember(['product/view', 'id' => 42]);
>
> // Remember URL specified with a name given
> Url::remember(['product/view', 'id' => 42], 'product');
> ```
>
> In the next
>   request we can get URL remembered in the following way:
>
> ```
> $url = Url::previous();
>   // or 
> $productUrl = Url::previous('product');
> ```